# Create groups of TestFlight internal testers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am using internal testing in TestFlight in App Store Connect. When I upload a build, sometimes I want it to go to only 1 or 2 App Store Connect Users, not all of them. Is there a way to do that? I could delete all the testers I don't want to send to, but then later I would have to reinvite them, which is a pain. I see that External testing allows grouping, but don't see a way to do that for Internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since a couple of days it is possible to do exactly what you want.

On the left side of the TestFlight page you can now add new internal tester groups: [image]

When you do so the following dialog will pop up:
[image]